# PHP как обратиться к ключу без упоминания объекта

Tags: php, объекты

В javascript есть очень удобный синтаксический сахар, с помощью которого можно вытащить ключи из объекта и обращаться к ним на прямую:

```
let obj = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  z: 3,
}

const { x, y, z } = obj;

console.log(x, y, z);
```

Вопрос в том как сделать то же самое в php:

```
$obj = [
  'x' => 1,
  'y' => 2,
  'z' => 3,
];

???

echo "{$x} {$y} {$z}";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php) — Импортирует переменные из массива в текущую таблицу символов

```
$obj = [
  'x' => 1,
  'y' => 2,
  'z' => 3,
];

extract($obj);

echo "{$x} {$y} {$z}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Увы нет. Точнее для неассоциативного массива есть `list`. Для ассоциативного только попробовать `list` с указанием ключа

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php#121094

```
$obj = [
  'x' => 1,
  'y' => 2,
  'z' => 3,
];

['x' => $x, 'y' => $y, 'z' => $z] = $obj;

echo "{$x} {$y} {$z}";
```

Comment: Как вариант можно применить `array_values` и написать `[$x, $y, $z] = ...`